# How to remove multiple select options based on dynamic value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have 2 select boxes, with the second showing a subset of all options based on the category in the first box. The second box contains ids and names, where the option value equals the id. I already filtered out the id's I am interested in and have them in an array. This will change each time and can be different sizes (filtering all users by groups). What I would like to do is take a clone of the complete options and then only show those whos id (or value) is present. So, compare the array of filtered values to the complete set. I did see a couple ways to remove options, but most were for only one value at a time or for fixed values, so it didn't exactly fit what I need and I can't figure out how to do this last step! Looks like the following:

```
<select id = 'doctor_select' >
<option value = '1' > John Doe </option>
<option value = '2' > Jane Doe </option>
```

.... etc

edit: solved for now by hiding all and doing a for each loop to enable the ones I need.

Comment: Are you trying to map ID's to options? You want only the options that match the id to show? How would you tell, is the option value related to ID?

Comment: The values are already the users id and it displays their name. The array of filtered users contains all the ids in whatever group is being searched, so I want to only show those options out of the total list.

Comment: where is the array? Objective is still not very clear either

Comment: I'm not sure how clear I can make it. I think it says it pretty clearly. I have some array of ids, it can be any number of them, I need to keep options with those values.

Comment: seeing your edit... you can't hide `<option>` tag!! It is not supported cross browser...most notably it will fail in IE and Safari

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, I'll get back to doing it the correct way .. but it should be alright, the site requires a browser that supports webrtc, so users should have firefox or chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I wouldn't do it like this, but you could clone the original combo and simply remove the unnecessary options from the DOM. Something like:

```
var newDoctorSelect=$("#doctor_select").clone();
$(newDoctorSelect).children("option").each(function() {
    if(some condition) $(this).remove();
});
$("#somewhere").append(newDoctorSelect);
```

But I'd recommend either using AJAX or storing the options in an object and populating the select when needed.

```
var optionsByCategory={
    "1":{"1":"One","3":"Three"},
    "2":{"2":"Two"}
};

$("#categorySelect").on("change",function() {
    var options=optionsByCategory[$(this).val()];
    //OR some AJAX call to retreive the options from the server instead
    $("#doctor_select option").remove();
    for(var k in options) $("#doctor_select").append($("<option>").val(k).text(options[k]));
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do this:

```
var options = getElementsByTagName("option"),
    elem,
    length = options.length;

for (var i = 0; i<length; i++) {
    if (!((elem = options[i]).value === IDYouWantToMatch)); elem.parentNode.removeChild(elem);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like the following using `filter()`

```
var $sel = $('#doctor_select'),
    $opts =  $sel.children();

var $filteredOpts = $opts.clone().filter(function(){
     return someArray.indexOf(this.value)>-1;
})
$sel.empty().append($filteredOpts);
```

The stored `$opts` can now be re-used for future changes